# How to make an array of objects with different label and value in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am using this.state.student in react to display (name,school,class.etc)..
how i change the "school" display to "college" without replacing the value of "School" in the api..

as i am new to code i tried

```
'var student = [ {"name", "school", "class"}];'
'student[1] = "college";'
```

but this just replaces the value. i just want to change the display
of "school" please help

Comment: show us how are you displayin the current one.

Comment: It will be helpful if you show how you are displaying the current school, just put your code inside ` ` by editing your answer.

Comment: Shouldn't your array look like `students=[{name: "student name", school: "school he studied"}]`?

Comment: If you are just showing student in a state do you really need the array. Isnt the student object itself not enough to set student state ?

Answer (score 0):

Check my code. I created a function `addToArray` that will accept a parameter of object then it will add it to the `students` array. This will give you an output of `[{ name: "John Doe", school: "College", class: "A" }]`

```
let students = [];

addToArray = student => {
  students.push({
    name: student.name,
    school: student.school,
    class: student.class
  });
  console.log(students);
};

this.addToArray({
  name: "John Doe",
  school: "College",
  class: "A"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to create an array of objects with different key and value pair,

```
var productArr = [];

productId = 1;
productName = 'Product Name';

productArr.push({ id: productId, name: productName });
```

Hope it'll work for you. Waiting for your response. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 var student = [ {"name": "school", "class":"XYZ"}];
student = [...student,{"name":"college","class":"ABC"}]
console.log(student)
```